# set fileformat=unix permanantly

Tags: mac, unix, terminal, file-format

When I built WSO2 product pack from terminal using `maven clean install` and going to run from terminal by issuing below command at product home directory

```
./bin/wso2server.sh
```

I got below error

```
-bash: ./bin/wso2server.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I could prevent this error by opening the `wso2server.sh` file in vi editor and by issuing `:set fileformat=unix` command and `:wq` command.

The problem is I have to do this every time when I build a pack using maven clean install command. how do I permanently set this command in system. I am on mac Yosemite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `<lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>` property in `bin.xml` where the `wso2server.sh` file copies to bin that uses maven assembly plugin. After that I can run `wso2server.sh` file without setting file format manually.